# Change font of separate strings detailTextLabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I change the font of one string in the detailTextLabel of my UITableViewCell?

```
NSString *detailStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",post.score,post.domain];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = detailStr;
```

I basically want the `post.score` string to be one color and the `post.domain` string to be another.

Comment: Have you checked my Answer ? I am quite sure that it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer : [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**.

**Try this :**

```
int count1 = [post.score length];
int count2 = [post.domain length];
NSMutableAttributedString *textLabelStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"%@ %@",post.score,post.domain];
[textLabelStr setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor], NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]} range:NSMakeRange(0, count1)];
[textLabelStr setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor], NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]} range:NSMakeRange(count1 + 1, count2)];
cell.detailTextLabel.attributedText = textLabelStr;
```

**Note :** Not tested, but Write the Code to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to use iOS6+ APIs then check out `NSAttributedString` and use `cell.detailTextLabel.attributedText = ...`

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for the `setAttributedText:` method of `UILabel`. You can pass an `NSAttributedString`to it in order to stylize different portions of the string in different ways.
I wrote a sample below that should do what you're asking for.

```
NSAttributedString *scoreAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[post score] attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]}];
NSAttributedString *domainAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[post domain] attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor]}];

NSMutableAttributedString *detailMutableAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
[detailMutableAttributedString appendAttributedString:scoreAttributedString];
[detailMutableAttributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" "]];
[detailMutableAttributedString appendAttributedString:domainAttributedString];

[[cell detailTextLabel] setAttributedText:detailMutableAttributedString];
```

Comment: For what my project requires, this is the answer that works for me. Thank You.